# nltk.corpus - 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, corpus

I am using below code and importing stop words from nltk

```
   #from nltk.corpus import words as word_corp
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
    en_words = nltk.corpus.words.words('en')
    stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
```

But error is `AttributeError: 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'setdefault' for ----> 3 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` this line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this issue as well - what versions of Python/spaCy are you using?

It happened to me with Python 3.9.1 + spaCy 2.2.4.

It worked for me after upgrading spaCy to 3.0.0 *OR* downgrading Python to 3.6.8 (didn't try other versions)

Comment: Yes, I did same.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this! I ran into this error with spaCy 2.2.4 and Python 3.7.

Comment: Spacy 2.3.1 works with Python 3.8.